# Java cookie not adding to browser

Tags: java

```
            CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
            CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();

            // create cookie
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserName", "John Doe");

            // add cookie to CookieStore for a
            // particular URL
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost");
            cookieJar.add(url.toURI(), cookie);
```

As I'v readed this code adds a cookie to the browser with every http request, but I've checked the browser cookies, and there's no `UserName` what is missing in this code?

Comment: I'm not sure on the procedure for creating cookies with Java to be honest so I can't give you an opinion on the code.  But have you tried checking to make sure the browswer accepts cookies, it's the kind of mistake I'd make! :)

Comment: A standalong java program will not add cookies to your browser. It does not even know of your browser.

Comment: Good point Zapl.  user3112115 can you explain where you are running the code?  Is it embedded into JSP?

Comment: I'am using HttpExchange class to send and receive data how can I integrate it there?

Answer (score 2):

**As I'v readed this code adds a cookie to the browser**

Not the browser but to the requests made by Java when your code use a url. When you'll do `url.openConnection()` the cookie will be added.

Comment: i'am using HttpExchange to send and receive data how can I integrate it there?